# org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: invalid memory alloc request size

Tags: postgresql, triggers, audit

I have around 100 + tables and wanted to audit changes to most of these tables. We  are using the generic audit trigger function [Audit Trigger 91 plus](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Audit_trigger_91plus)

Upon adding the audit trigger to handfull of tables, the trigger worked perfectly fine. Later when I added the trigger to 80 plus tables, I get the 'org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: invalid memory alloc request size' error upon saving or updating any record from hibernate.

Following is the stacktrace.

```
caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: invalid memory alloc request size 1199606566
  Where: PL/pgSQL function if_modified_func() line 51 at assignment
SQL statement "INSERT INTO  logged_actions VALUES (audit_row.*)"
PL/pgSQL function if_modified_func() line 58 at SQL statement
SQL statement "INSERT INTO  logged_actions VALUES (audit_row.*)"
PL/pgSQL function if_modified_func() line 58 at SQL statement
SQL statement "INSERT INTO  logged_actions VALUES (audit_row.*)"
PL/pgSQL function if_modified_func() line 58 at SQL statement
SQL statement "INSERT INTO  logged_actions VALUES (audit_row.*)"
PL/pgSQL function if_modified_func() line 58 at SQL statement
SQL statement "INSERT INTO  logged_actions VALUES (audit_row.*)"
PL/pgSQL function if_modified_func() line 58 at SQL statement
```

This issue happens only after I add the trigger to all the tables. When I drop all the triggers, the error goes away.

Is adding audit trigger to all tables causing this issue. Is there any variable I could set to fix the 'invalid memory alloc request size' issue?

Comment: At a guess, the json or hstore row being produced is just too big for single value.

Comment: I though hstore is varlena and store upto 1GB. I am sure that my row data is far less than 1GB.

Comment: Did you add the trigger to the table you're writing audit information into? That'd probably do it.

Comment: Awesome.  The issue was just as you pointed out. Thanks a million !!!